# Go SQL, scanning a row as a slice?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

**closing note:
This question does not ask "how can I find the number of columns returned?" which is len(row.Columns()). It is asking a Go-related question concerning the `rows.Scan()` function.**

How can I extract all the columns in a row into a slice or equivalent?  For example

```
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from foo")
    for rows.Next() {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", rows)
```

I would like to extract the data in `lastcols` as a slice.

```
&{dc:0xc000486000 releaseConn:0x5e20c0 rowsi:0xc0000cf180 cancel:<nil>
closeStmt:<nil> closemu:{w:{state:0 sema:0} writerSem:0
readerSem:0 readerCount:0 readerWait:0} closed:false lasterr:<nil>
lastcols:[abc 123 foo {wall:0 ext:0 loc:0xc0000ec000}]}
```

context:

- for debugging, I would like to `select * from sometable` and display the results without knowing the table format in advance.
- github.com/lib/pg SQL driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the number of columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658395/find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i get a count(\*) of all the columns in a table? Using PostgreSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087945/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-all-the-columns-in-a-table-using-postgresql)

Comment: This is from memory and I'm on my phone and can't verify: Use [rows.Columns](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Columns) (or ColumnTypes) to determine how many columns there are. make a []interface{} with the same length. Scan into the slice: `rows.Scan(mySlice...)`. You may have to create (pointers to) values with concrete types at each slice index before scanning (based on info returned by rows.ColumnTypes).

Comment: @Luuk It is a Go-related API question, not how to find the number of columns.

Comment: @nbk This is not a Postgresql question, it is a Go API question.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Does it matter where you get the information from?

Comment: @nbk I added the information that I'm using the postgresql driver in case it was useful in answering the question.  The actual number of columns returned is len(rows.Columns()).

Comment: Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17845619/11810946) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51731423/11810946) provide options (these are go specific and address the use of `rows.Scan()` :-) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Columns with `rows.Columns()` then you can make a slice to fetch the data.

```
columns, err := rows.Columns()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

values := make([]interface{}, len(columns))
for i := range values {
    values[i] = new(interface{})
}

err = rows.Scan(values...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```